# Difference between lowess and regression plot

Tags: regression, scatterplot

Why there is difference between lowess smoother plot and regression plot in the following plot?

[image]

I run packages: "datasets" "utils" "graphics" "stats" "methods" in RStudio.

Comment: Could you give us some background that explains why you would expect the two plots to be similar?

Comment: How would you make the lowess smoother look like the regression plot? (what could you change?)

Comment: what implementation of lowess is this/what commands did you use?

Comment: I just used scatterplot(Y,X) in R and I got this result. I want to know in what situations these two plots are the same?

Comment: Which package are you using? "scatterplot" is not in vanilla R. It's not possible to answer if we don't know how they've implemented the function. It doesn't look to me like it uses a fraction-of-x type span

Comment: I use RStudio...

Comment: So do I, yet I don't have a function called `scatterplot`. Type `?scatterplot` in your RStudio session, and edit into your post which package's `scatterplot` function you're running.

Answer (score 2):

The lowess smooth is a *local* regression (an estimate of $E(Y|X=x)$ based on nearby points to $x$).

The green line is an overall linear fit.

Obviously if  $E(Y|X=x)$ is not close to linear over the whole range the two won't look similar (and then the green line would be inappropriate as a description).

On the other hand, if the span of the lowess smooth is too narrow, it may be responding to only a few points (that  can most easily happen if the implementation uses a width rather than a fraction of $X$ to determine the width of the kernel, but it's possible to set the span too narrow -- or wide).

In the case that lowess is overfitting, it would be sensible to make the lowess span larger.

In your plot, the green line clearly *doesn't* fit the data with lowest x-values well, nor the larger x-values (past x=1500 or so the relationship looks essentially flat to me).

It may make more sense to smooth a transformed Y and X (possibly logs in both); you'll see more detail.